# How to generate jar files of dependencies from maven project multi-module and spring boot

Tags: maven

I have

- project A (parent)

  - pom.xml
- project B

  - pom.xml
- project C

  - pom.xml
- project D

  - pom.xml contains (dependencies B and C)

when I build project D, I have not B.jar and C.jar. I have 2 folders named B and C.

I need B.jar and C.jar. Please, how to do that?

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <groupId>org.exemple.demo</groupId>
  <artifactId>ticket</artifactId>
  <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>pom</packaging>

  <name>ticket</name>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

  <properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
 <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
 <java.version>1.8</java.version>
  </properties>


  <parent> 
 <groupId> org.springframework.boot </groupId> 
 <artifactId> spring-boot-starter-parent </artifactId> 
 <version> 2.1.2.RELEASE </version> 
   </parent>

 <!-- Ajouter des dépendances typiques pour une application Web --> 
 <dependencies> 
  <dependency> 
   <groupId> org.springframework.boot </groupId> 
   <artifactId> spring-boot-starter-web </artifactId> 
  </dependency> 

  <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
      <scope>test</scope>
  </dependency>
 </dependencies>

 <!-- Le package est un fichier jar exécutable --> 
 <build> 
  <plugins> 
   <plugin> 
    <groupId> org.springframework.boot </groupId> 
    <artifactId> spring-boot-maven-plugin </artifactId> 
   </plugin > 
  </plugins> 
 </build>
 
  <modules>
    <module>ticket-consumer</module>
    <module>ticket-provider</module>
    <module>ticket-business</module>
    <module>ticket-webapp</module>
    <module>ticket-model</module>
    <module>ticket-technical</module>
  </modules>
</project>


the code above is the parent.

<!-- begin snippet: js hide: false console: true babel: false -->
```

This code has many dependencies. but, the build of this project don't generate jar files.

Answer (score 0):

this child with dependencies:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<project xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd" xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <parent>
    <groupId>org.exemple.demo</groupId>
    <artifactId>ticket</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  </parent>

  <groupId>org.exemple.demo</groupId>
  <artifactId>ticket-webapp</artifactId>
  <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <name>ticket-webapp</name>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

  <properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
  </properties>

  <dependencies>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>3.8.1</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.exemple.demo</groupId>
      <artifactId>ticket-provider</artifactId>
      <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.exemple.demo</groupId>
      <artifactId>ticket-model</artifactId>
      <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </dependency>

  </dependencies>

  <build> 
        <plugins> 
            <plugin> 
                <groupId> org.springframework.boot </groupId> 
                <artifactId> spring-boot-maven-plugin </artifactId> 
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>repackage</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <archive>
                            <manifest>
                                <mainClass>
                                    org.exemple.demo.App
                                </mainClass>
                            </manifest>
                            </archive>
                            <descriptorRefs>
                                <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                            </descriptorRefs>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin > 
        </plugins> 
    </build>
</project>
```